# is it possible to remove the png background reactangle when print with cavas

Tags: typescript, canvas

I have a png that was removed background, now I want to print this photo using html 5 cavas(The original image was base64 string) with blue background color. This is my typescript code:

```
export function downloadPhoto(bgColor: string, imgId: string) {
    const element = document.getElementById(imgId) as HTMLImageElement;
    if (!element) {
        return;
    }
    const canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    canvas.width = element.naturalWidth;
    canvas.height = element.naturalHeight;
    const context = canvas.getContext('2d');
    if (!context) {
        return;
    }
    context.imageSmoothingEnabled = true;
    context.drawImage(element as HTMLImageElement, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    const imageData = context.getImageData(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    if (bgColor !== "origin") {
        const pixelData = imageData.data;
        const rgba = RdColor.colorToRGBA(bgColor);
        if (!rgba) {
            return;
        }
        const r = rgba[0];
        const g = rgba[1];
        const b = rgba[2];
        for (let i = 0; i < pixelData.length; i += 4) {
            const red = pixelData[i];
            const green = pixelData[i + 1];
            const blue = pixelData[i + 2];
            const alpha = pixelData[i + 3];
            if (red === 0 && green === 0 && blue === 0 && alpha === 0) {
                pixelData[i] = r;
                pixelData[i + 1] = g;
                pixelData[i + 2] = b;
                pixelData[i + 3] = 255;
            }
        }
    }
    context.putImageData(imageData, 0, 0);
    const dataURL = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
    const link = document.createElement('a');
    link.href = dataURL;
    link.download = 'image.png';
    link.click();
}
```

this code works fine, but have a problem that the output image contains the png background rectangle. the hair contains a white edge:

[image]

is it possible to remove the white(gray) edge? what should I do to remove it? I have tried to add this code seem did not work:

```
context.imageSmoothingEnabled = true;
```

Comment: Does set [globalCompositeOperation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/globalCompositeOperation) with different value works?

Comment: I am replaced with another way to fil rectangle. hope will fix this issue.